# How to intercept or aop javax.sql.Datasource.getConnection() using spring aop

Tags: spring-aop

I am trying to aspect the javax.sql.Datasource.getConnection() so that I can set clientInfo properties before the connection is used.

I tried spring ConnectionInterceptor with COnnectionPreparer but it did not work.

I tried pointcut with javax.sql.datasource.getConnection() but not working.

now , am trying pointcut with the below but my advise is not executed rather the call just passes through.

pom.xml has

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
         </dependency>
```

main class

```java
 @SpringBootApplication
    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan({ "com.xyz" })
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
    public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

         // spring configuration here
         // cxf end point configuration
}
```

aspect class

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class ClientIdentifierConnectionPreparer {

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(java.sql.Connection org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHandle.getConnection())", returning="conn")
        public void prepare(Connection conn) {
           System.out.println("prepare connection aspect 1");        
        }


        @Before("execution(java.sql.Connection org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHandle.getConnection())")
        public void prepareBefore() {
           System.out.println("prepare connection aspect 2");        
        }
 }
```

can you pls help

Comment: I need some more coordinates: (1) Have you ever gotten any aspect to fire, maybe with a simple pointcut such as `execution(* *(..))`? (2) If so, please also show the Spring configuration for AOP and the relevant beans and also the code you are trying to intercept. Ideally, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes, I got the aspect to fire.

spring config is. Removed the @ symbol before the annotations as it is not allowed

SpringBootApplication
Configuration
EnableAutoConfiguration
ComponentScan({ "com.xyz" })
EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

Comment: Please just update the question and use code formatting there, then notify me in a comment. And please also add the other bits I asked for. Generally, please try to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or as close as you can get. Programming problems are much more fun to solve if reproduceable. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: @kriegaex i have updated the question. Hope this helps. Apologies, I am new in the site.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a bit. But where is the code you are trying to intercept? In order to find out why aspects do not work, the aspects themselves are necessary but insufficient. I also need to see the target classes incl. package names and class-level annotations.